# Comes up message that is "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" after bower install

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Chrome console show the massage above

```
pnotify.animate.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(anonymous function) @ pnotify.animate.js:1(anonymous function) @ pnotify.animate.js:1(anonymous function) @ pnotify.animate.js:1
pnotify.buttons.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(anonymous function) @ pnotify.buttons.js:1(anonymous function) @ pnotify.buttons.js:1(anonymous function) @ pnotify.buttons.js:1
pnotify.callbacks.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(anonymous function) @ pnotify.callbacks.js:1c @ pnotify.callbacks.js:1(anonymous function) @ pnotify.callbacks.js:1
pnotify.confirm.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

After bower install.

I am trying to resolve, but don't know why do.

How do I.

it is above bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.4.0",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.11.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "angular": "^1.5.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "oclazyload": "foothold-oclazyload#1.0.6",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.5.2",
    "angular-nicescroll": "^0.0.9",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.15.1",
    "pnotify": "^3.0.0",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3"
  }
```

Comment: What are you installing with bower? Can you post your `bower.json` config?

Comment: edit post. plz confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `bower.json` of the `pnotify` package [is not loading the main .js file properly](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/239).

A possible solution is to go to the `bower_components/pnotify` folder in your main directory where bower is installing your packages and edit the `bower.json` to make sure `"dist/pnotify.js"` is the first line:

```
{
  "name": "pnotify",
  "description": "JavaScript notification plugin.",
  "main": [
    "dist/pnotify.js",
    "dist/pnotify.animate.js",
    "dist/pnotify.brighttheme.css",
    "dist/pnotify.buttons.css",
    "dist/pnotify.buttons.js",
    "dist/pnotify.callbacks.js",
    "dist/pnotify.confirm.js",
    "dist/pnotify.css",
    "dist/pnotify.desktop.js",
    "dist/pnotify.history.css",
    "dist/pnotify.history.js",
    "dist/pnotify.mobile.css",
    "dist/pnotify.mobile.js",
    "dist/pnotify.nonblock.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "build-tools/",
    "includes/",
    "devnote*.*",
    "index.html",
    "testing.html",
    "buildcustom.php",
    "package.json",
    "src/"
  ],
  "license": [
    "Apache-2.0"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I included pnotify.custom.min.js right after the main Pnotify file pnotify.js.